# How to determine integer types that are twice the width as `int` and `unsigned`?

Tags: c, integer, portability

Values of intermediate multiplication typically need twice the number of bits as inputs.

```
 // Example
int foo(int a, int b, int carry, int rem) {
  int2x c;  // Some type that is twice as wide at `int`
  c = (int2x)a * b + carry;
  return (int) (c % rem);
}
```

Considering the potential for padding, (which appears to limit `sizeof()` usefulness) and non-2`s complement integers (which limits bit dibbling),  ...

> Does the following always create the needed type? (when it exists.)
> If not, how to code at least a reasonable solution, even if not entirely portable?

---

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if LONG_MAX/2/INT_MAX - 2 == INT_MAX
  typedef long int2x;
  typedef unsigned long unsigned2x;
#elif LLONG_MAX/2/INT_MAX - 2 == INT_MAX
  typedef long long int2x;
  typedef unsigned long long unsigned2x;
#elif INTMAX_MAX/2/INT_MAX - 2 == INT_MAX
  typedef intmax_t int2x;
  typedef uintmax_t unsigned2x;
#else
  #error int2x/unsigned2x not available
#endif
```

---

[Edit]
Qualify:"always", if `long`, `long long` and `intmax_t`, do not work it is OK to `#error`.
What I want to know is if at least 1 of `long`, `long long`, or `intmax_t` will work, will `int2x` be correctly typed?

Notes: The above assumes `xxx_MAX` are some odd power-of-2 minus 1.  Maybe a good assumption?  The above works on at least 2 platforms, but that is hardly a great portability test.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question, but for a "reasonable solution" **AND** "entirely portable", why not just stay on the safe side and use `long long` in any case? You're casting back to `int` at the end anyway, so what's the point in being "cheap" on the intermediate variable?

Comment: No, it doesn't capture the weirdo possibilities. It says nowhere that such a type as you are looking for must exist. I'd compare `INT_MAX` with `INT16_MAX` and `INT32_MAX` to see if `int` is `16` or `32` bit wide. Then I'd use `int_least32_t` or `int_least64_t`, respectively, for `int2x`.

Comment: This seems an exercise in futility; why not just use explicitly sized types (`int16_t`, etc.) if you want reproducible maths?

Comment: @barak manos Using `long long` when `long` would work could quadruple execution time.  A driving problem, of which th is is simplified, is a  many `int` in length.  As much of the code used used in embedded and also PC based, the `int` can easily be 16, or 32.

Comment: Note that the problem is not necessarily solvable. In particular, `int`, `long`, and `long long` could all be exactly the same size (as long as they're 64-bit or larger). In this case you can break the multiplication down into half-sized units yourself rather than using `#error`, though...

Comment: @R..  Agreed that integer types could all be the same size, but at least the `#else #error` would catch the problem - thought not solve it.  Using half-width multiplication would be an approach

Comment: @Jens Gustedt 1) Please provide a sample "weirdo possibilities" that fails. 2) Does not the `#else #error` capture the "type ... must exist."?  3) Thought of the `UINT16_MAX/UINT32_MAX` approach but that has trouble with the pre-processor.  Should have re-considered the `INT16_MAX/INT32_MAX` approach.  That appears more straight-forward, other than it doesn’t handle 18/36 bit `int` and other non-power-of-2 widths – I would suspect those are rare these days – but IDK.

Comment: @chux, `int` could be 24 bit wide, for example.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt  Agree `int` could be 24-bit.  But how does the posted solution fail for 24-bit, especially given such a machine may have a `long` or `long long` of 48-bit?   (Aside: modern day PICs have a 24-bit integer type - though use 16-bit for `int`.)

Comment: @chux they *may* have a 48 bit `long` or `long long`, but also these *may* have 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Appended an edit to deal with `weirdo possibilities`.

Comment: @chux where you say "some odd power-of-2 minus 1" did you mean **even power-of-two**?

Comment: @Weather Vane I do mean "some odd power-of-2 minus 1".  To clarify: Every signed integer type I have worked with (except 9-bit char) had a max value like `pow(2,31)-1` or `pow(2,some_odd)-1`, etc.  OTOH, maximum value of unsigned integer types, that I have seen, have always been `pow(2,some_even)-1` .

Comment: @chux mybad yes of course, brain glitch.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth (Sorry for the late response) as in "why not just use explicitly sized types"?  In implementing some functions that performed with standard structures like `struct tm`, many of the fields are `int` and their type is not for me to alter.  Code often need to cope with something like the sum `tm.tm_year + tm.tm_mon/12`.  Without a type like `int2x`, the code to detect overflow is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 5):

The assumption that all *_MAX constants are of the form `(2^n)-1` is valid. See *6.2.6 Representations of Types*, and particularly *6.2.6.2 Integer types*, where the representations of unsigned integer types and the positive values of signed integer types are fully defined as pure binary, thus yielding a maximum which is one less than a power of two.

Comment: I had hope to garner an answer than addressed the post more clearly with the bounty.  But to no avail.  As this answer better addresses parts of the post clearly, +50 to you.

Comment: Bounties don't seem to be as prominently displayed as they used to. I haven't noticed bounties for a long time... :-(

Answer (score 0):

For `signed` types it's better to work just with the **range of values** of the considered types and compare them.

Firstly, one would try to calculate `INT_MAX*INTMAX+INT_MAX` in order to have the maximum possible value in the expression `a*b+carry`. By casting to `intmax_t` seems the more reasonable approach:

```
 #define MAX_EXPRESSION ((intmax_t) INT_MAX * INTMAX + INT_MAX)
```

However, we can fall in trouble if the true mathematical value of `MAX_EXPRESSION` is greater than `INTMAX_MAX`. So, let's do some maths to surround this problem.

Let's denote *c = INT_MAX* and *m = INTMAX_MAX*. We want to know if `c*c+c <= m`, mathematically speaking. This leads us to the inequation: `c <= (m - c) / c`. Since the division is integer, the result is truncated, so the exact maths are lost in the last operation. Thus, we have to write a more precise expression, like this: `c <= floor((m - c) / c) + fractional_part_of((m - c) / c).

If `c > floor((m - c) / c)`, strictly, then `c >= floor((m - c) / c) + 1 > (m - c) / c`, where the division is taken in mathematical sense (with exact decimals). which gives us `c*c+c > m`, contradiction. So, we conclude that `c <= floor((m - c) / c)`, again, mathematically speaking.

This expression is more handy in **C**, because *m - c* will give us a correct value when calculated with type `intmax_t` (in other words: it's not an **out-of-range** value). Now, the division `(m - c) / c` will give us an integer number in the range of `intmax_t`, again, although possibly truncated, because the division is integer. Actually, it gives us the value `floor((m - c) / c`, without hesitation.

It this comparisson gives true, then we can say that `c*c+c` is representable in the greatest signed integer type of your systen, that is, `intmax_t`. In particular: there exists a signed integer type which is capable of representing the value `c*c+c` in your system.

Now, in **C** code, we can write:

```
  #define c INT_MAX
  #define m INTMAX_MAX

  #if (c <= (m - c) / c)
     // There exists a signed type in your system
     // such that INT_MAX*INTMAX+INT_MAX is representable
     // as a value in that type.
  #else
      #error Sorry, the size of INT_MAX cannot be doubled...
  #endif
```

Once you have determined that `intmax_t` does the job, you simply can start a search for the signed integer type with minimal rank that solves the problem: We can ask again the same question we did for `intmax_t`, for example for `long` and `long long`:

```
  #include <stdint.h>
  #include <limits.h>
  #define c INT_MAX

  #if (c <= (INTMAX_MAX - c) / c)
      #if (c <= (LLONG_MAX - c) / c)
          #if (c <= (LONG_MAX - c) / c)
             typedef long int2x;
          #else
             typedef long long int2x;
          #endif
      #else
         typedef intmax_t int2x;
      #endif
  #else
      #error Sorry, the size of type "int" cannot be doubled...
  #endif
```

Comment: Thought: could not `INT_MIN*INT_MIN + INT_MAX` be greater than `INT_MAX*INT_MAX+INT_MAX`?

Comment: Yes, it can. mmmm... Perhaps it would be enough if I add a comment about this issue at the end of the answer.

Comment: But then does not that larger value affect the rest of the equations to the point they differ little from the post?

Comment: Probably the negative values require an alternative analysis. I cannot do that in this moment. i will think about, later.