# Add integers safely, and prove the safety

Tags: c++, c, standards, verification, correctness

Programming course assignment asks to

- write a (safe) function that adds two integers, and
- show that the function is safe.

The following code represents my solution.
I am not an expert on the C standard (or on formal verification methods).
So I would like to ask:
Are there better (or different) solutions?

Thank you

```
#include <limits.h>

/*
      Try to add integers op1 and op2.
      Return
        0 (success) or
        1 (overflow prevented).
      In case of success, write the sum to res.
*/

int safe_int_add(int * res,
                 int op1,
                 int op2) {
  if (op2 < 0) {

    /**  We have: **********************************************/
    /*                                                         */
    /*          0  >     op2                                   */
    /*          0  <   - op2                                   */
    /*    INT_MIN  <   - op2 + INT_MIN                         */
    /*    INT_MIN  <           INT_MIN - op2                   */
    /*    INT_MIN  <=          INT_MIN - op2                   */
    /*                                                         */
    /**  Also, we have: ****************************************/
    /*                                                         */
    /*              op2  >=    INT_MIN                         */
    /*            - op2  <=  - INT_MIN                         */
    /*    INT_MIN - op2  <=  - INT_MIN + INT_MIN               */
    /*    INT_MIN - op2  <=  0                                 */
    /*    INT_MIN - op2  <=  INT_MAX                           */
    /*                                                         */
    /**  Hence, we have: ***************************************/
    /*                                                         */
    /*    INT_MIN  <=  INT_MIN - op2  <=  INT_MAX              */
    /*                                                         */
    /*    i.e. the following subtraction does not overflow.    */
    /*                                                         */
    /***********************************************************/

    if (op1 < INT_MIN - op2) {
      return 1;
    }

    /**  We have: *********************************/
    /*                                            */
    /*    INT_MIN - op2  <=  op1                  */
    /*    INT_MIN        <=  op1 + op2            */
    /*                                            */
    /**  Also, we have: ***************************/
    /*                                            */
    /*          op2  <   0                        */
    /*    op1 + op2  <   op1                      */
    /*    op1 + op2  <   INT_MAX                  */
    /*    op1 + op2  <=  INT_MAX                  */
    /*                                            */
    /**  Hence, we have: **************************/
    /*                                            */
    /*    INT_MIN  <=  op1 + op2  <=  INT_MAX     */
    /*                                            */
    /*    i.e. the addition does not overflow.    */
    /*                                            */
    /**********************************************/

  }
  else {

    /**  We have: **********************************************/
    /*                                                         */
    /*              op2  >=  0                                 */
    /*            - op2  <=  0                                 */
    /*    INT_MAX - op2  <=  INT_MAX                           */
    /*                                                         */
    /**  Also, we have: ****************************************/
    /*                                                         */
    /*              INT_MAX  >=    op2                         */
    /*            - INT_MAX  <=  - op2                         */
    /*    INT_MAX - INT_MAX  <=  - op2 + INT_MAX               */
    /*                    0  <=  - op2 + INT_MAX               */
    /*                    0  <=          INT_MAX - op2         */
    /*              INT_MIN  <=          INT_MAX - op2         */
    /*                                                         */
    /**  Hence, we have: ***************************************/
    /*                                                         */
    /*    INT_MIN  <=  INT_MAX - op2  <=  INT_MAX              */
    /*                                                         */
    /*    i.e. the following subtraction does not overflow.    */
    /*                                                         */
    /***********************************************************/

    if (op1 > INT_MAX - op2) {
      return 1;
    }

    /**  We have: *********************************/
    /*                                            */
    /*    op1        <=  INT_MAX - op2            */
    /*    op1 + op2  <=  INT_MAX                  */
    /*                                            */
    /**  Also, we have: ***************************/
    /*                                            */
    /*          0  <=  op2                        */
    /*        op1  <=  op2 + op1                  */
    /*    INT_MIN  <=  op2 + op1                  */
    /*    INT_MIN  <=        op1 + op2            */
    /*                                            */
    /**  Hence, we have: **************************/
    /*                                            */
    /*    INT_MIN  <=  op1 + op2  <=  INT_MAX     */
    /*                                            */
    /*    i.e. the addition does not overflow.    */
    /*                                            */
    /**********************************************/

  }

  *res = op1 + op2;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your code is working properly, you can try the same question at [codereview.se]

Comment: Define "safe", please.

Comment: @KirilKirov: It must mean "avoiding overflow", since that's the only unsafe thing that can happen with integer arithmetic.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - unless there are other threads, messing with `res`, for example.

Comment: `INT_MIN - op2` underflows, since `op2` is negative. Also returning `1` on error is a very bad idea, because you never know if the result is `1` or an error occured. My idea would be to use `long long int`s, add them and check if the results fits in an `int`.

Comment: Somehow related: [safe integer](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/articles/knowledge/coding-practices/safe-integer-operations). In the gcc part a rather simple way of checking the result is shown. Maybe this can help to "proove" your correctness.

Comment: @nwp: the problem with the `long long` approach is that `int` could also be 64 bit.

Comment: @nwp. `INT_MIN - op2` does _not_ underflow.

Comment: @tobi303 the example referenced "Checking for overflow when adding two signed integers" invokes undefined behavior (`int` overflow) with `const Wtype w = a + b`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect integer overflow in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Comment: @chux actually I was refering to the `if (b >= 0 ? w < a : w > a)` that is used to check (i.e. "prove") that the addition was succesful

Comment: @tobi303 Since `if (b >= 0 ? w < a : w > a)` depends on `w` and `const Wtype w = a + b` is UB on overflow, that check code is too late, UB has all ready happened.  [Elvis has all ready left the building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_has_left_the_building).

Comment: @chux I think I got your point. Lets assume he has (1) a safe function that adds two integers, then he could still use this condition to (2) argue/show/prove that there really was no overflow (assumed overflow is all that has to be checked to call it safe).

Comment: @tobi303   Yes, Think of a smart compiler that _knows_ `int` overflow is UB and figures out `if (b >= 0 ? w < a : w > a)` could only be true on overflow.  Since overflow is UB, that optimizing compiler simple drops that line of code as it is not needed.

Comment: @chux I think I got your point. For a safe function that really is safe, any check/proof is superfluous and can be optimized away. However, for an assignment I personally would try to argue based on a simple check rather than optimizing this check away ;)

Comment: @tobi303 For a safe function that really is safe, the check needs to be done _before_ the addition.  A check _after_ an addition that may overflow is UB and is superfluous.  A check _before_ potential UB, that prevents UB, is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's approach is optimally portably staying within type `int` as well as safe - no undefined behavior (UB) with any combination of `int`.  It is independent of a particular `int` format (2's complement, 2's complement, sign-magnitude).

In C, `int` overflow/(underflow) is undefined behavior.  So code, if staying with `int`, must determine overflow potential before-hand.  With `op1` positive, `INT_MAX - op1` cannot overflow.  Also, with `op1` negative, `INT_MIN - op1` cannot overflow.  So with edges properly calculated and tested, `op1 + op2` will not overflow.

```
// Minor re-write:
int safe_int_add(int * res, int op1, int op2) {
  assert(res != NULL);
  if (op1 >= 0) { 
    if (op2 > INT_MAX - op1) return 1;
  } else { 
    if (op2 < INT_MIN - op1) return 1;
  }
  *res = op1 + op2;
  return 0;
}
```

[See also](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37178/29485)

If a know [wider type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25982992/2410359) is available, code could use

```
int safe_int_add_wide(int * res, int op1, int op2) {
  int2x sum = (int2x) op1 + op2;
  if (sum < INT_MIN || sum > INT_MAX) return 1;
  *res = (int) sum;
  return 0;
}
```

Approaches using `unsigned`, etc. first need to qualify that `UINT_MAX` >= `INT_MAX - INT_MIN`.  This is usually true, but not guaranteed by the C standard.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

If the input arguments have different signs then the result is *always* computable without any risk of overflow.

If both input arguments are negative, then compute `-safe_int_add(res, -op1, -op2);`. (You'll need to check that `op1` or `op2` are not the largest negative in 2s compliment).

The function that needs thought is the one that adds two positive numbers: convert your two inputs to unsigned types. Add those. That is *guaranteed* to not overflow the unsigned type since you can store (at least) twice as large values in an unsigned int than in a signed int (exactly twice for 1s compliment, one more than that for 2s compliment).

Then only attempt a conversion back to signed if the unsigned value is small enough.

Comment: Very concise answer. Before I read the question I wasnt even aware that one has to be careful with adding integers (well if I think about it, of course one has to be...) and its good to know that it is that easy to avoid problems

Comment: 1) "guaranteed to not overflow the unsigned type since you can store (at least) twice as large values in an unsigned int than in a signed int" is not guaranteed by the C spec.   C only guarantees `UINT_MAX >= INT_MIX`. It is common though with 2's complement and no padding to have a 2x range.   2) OP's approach works for all `int` including 2's complement `INT_MIN` without special handling unlike this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the implementation of JDK 8, which has a fine reference to the book *Hacker's Delight* from Henry S. Warren, Jr. here:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/b971b51bec01

```
public static int addExact(int x, int y) {
    int r = x + y;
    // HD 2-12 Overflow iff both arguments have the opposite sign of the result
    if (((x ^ r) & (y ^ r)) < 0) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("integer overflow");
    }
    return r;
}
```

In my version of the book, it is chapter 2-13 though. There you can find a lengthy explanation about the whole issue.

Comment: if `x+y` overflows, the result is undefined behavior (C11dr §3.4.3 3).  So any code after `int r = x + y;` is too late.