# How to normalize a matrix in C?

Tags: c, matrix

How to normalize a matrix?

Suppose I have a 2x3 matrix:
1 2 3
4 5 6
The normalized matrix would be:
`1/sqrt(pow(2,2) + pow(3,2)) 2/sqrt(pow(2,2) + pow(3,2)) 3/sqrt(pow(2,2) + pow(3,2))

4/sqrt(pow(5,2) + pow(6,2)) 5/sqrt(pow(5,2) + pow(6,2)) 6/sqrt(pow(5,2) + pow(6,2))`

This is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){  
    int rows, cols, rowCounter, colCounter, r, c;  
    int initial[100], inputMatrix[100][100], rowSum[100] = {0}, norm[100][100], square[100] = {0};


    printf("Enter size of a matrix\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols);
    printf("Enter matrix of size %dX%d\n", rows, cols);
    /* Input matrix */
    for(rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < rows; rowCounter++){
        for(colCounter = 0; colCounter < cols; colCounter++){
            scanf("%d", &inputMatrix[rowCounter][colCounter]);
        }
    }



    for(r = 0; r < rows; r++)  
       {  
           for(c = 1; c < cols; c++)  
           {  
               float a;  
               a == inputMatrix[r][c];  
                square[r] += pow(a, 2);  
           }  
           printf("%.2lf ", square[r]);  
       }  

        for(rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < rows; rowCounter++)  
       {  
           for(colCounter = 0; colCounter < cols; colCounter++)  
           {  
               norm[rowCounter][colCounter] == (inputMatrix[rowCounter][colCounter]) / sqrt(square[rowCounter]);  
           }  
       }  
       printf("\nNormalized Matrix:\n");  
       for(rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < rows; rowCounter++)  
       {  
           for(colCounter = 0; colCounter < cols; colCounter++)  
           {  
               printf("%.3lf ", norm[rowCounter][colCounter]);  
           }  
           printf("\n");  
       }  

        getch();  
        return 0;  
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my code it gives me the square to be  0.000 0.000
and norm is all 0.000

Comment: You understand that many of your declarations are `int` instead of `double` or `float`, right?  So for instance your `printf` that used `%lf` format is guaranteed to fail if you pass it `square[r]`, since that will be passed as an `int`.  Fix your declarations to be `double`.

Comment: And worse, your `norm` matrix is `int`.  That means any fractional part will be discarded.  Get rid of *all* the `int` declarations for your matrix values.

Comment: Also, *turn on compiler warnings* and *fix them* before posting code here.  Modern C compilers should warn about the incorrect data types being passed to `printf`.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `==` here:

```
for(r = 0; r < rows; r++)  
   {  
       for(c = 1; c < cols; c++)  
       {  
           float a;  
           a == inputMatrix[r][c];   //look here
            square[r] += pow(a, 2);  
       }
```

It should be:

```
for(r = 0; r < rows; r++)  
   {  
       for(c = 1; c < cols; c++)  
       {  
           float a;  
           a = inputMatrix[r][c];  
            square[r] += pow(a, 2);  
       }
```

The same here:

```
norm[rowCounter][colCounter] == (inputMatrix[rowCounter][colCounter]) / sqrt(square[rowCounter]);
```

It should be:

```
norm[rowCounter][colCounter] = (inputMatrix[rowCounter][colCounter]) / sqrt(square[rowCounter]);
```

And you should be careful here:

```
int initial[100], inputMatrix[100][100], rowSum[100] = {0}, norm[100][100], square[100] = {0};
```

Are you sure about use `int` for all of this declarations?
I think you should use `double` or `float` instead, at least in some of them.

Comment: Thank you @Martin but I also tried that but the output is still the same.

Here is the sample of my output   [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tNsFn.jpg

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code, I'll try to address the most important ones.

Your `norm` matrix is a 2D array of int as `inputMatrix`, but you have to use an array of float or double to correctly store the result and to perform the right calculation. In C if both of the terms of a division are integers types an integer division (like: 3/2 = 1, not 1.5) is performed, which is not what you need.

Another mistake is to use `==` instead of `=` to perform an assignment. In C `==` is the 'equal to' relational operation.

***EDIT***

As @**chux** pointed out it would be wiser to choose a more accurate type for `a` and `square[]`. Using `long long int` will (may) prevent numeric overflow in case the elements of the matrix are too big for their square or the sum of them to be reprensented by an `int`.

Be aware that if you decide to use double instead there are other subtle numerical issues concernig the sum of small number (and the order in which it is performed) represented by floating point types. So, as a partial remedy, you can use `long double` (if it really has more precision then `double` in your environment) for `a` and `square`.

***EDIT 2***

In the question and in comment you say that the first element of each row of the matrix is supposed to be "constant in the matrix" so it doesn't take part to the sum of squares in your code and in the example you gave, but in both of them they are updated in the next loop. I'm not sure of what is going on, so I corrected my code to mimic the behavior of yours.

Here is a working corrected version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {  
    int rows, cols, r, c;  
    // you may think about dynamical allocation here
    int inputMatrix[100][100], rowSum[100] = {0};
    // it's better to use a type that can manage bigger numbers to avoid numeric overflow
    long long int a, square[100] = {0}; 
    // your starting matrix can be a matrix of int but the normalized one need to
    // contain floating point numbers
    double norm[100][100], k;

    printf("Enter size of a matrix\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols);
    printf("Enter matrix of size %dX%d\n", rows, cols);
    /* Input matrix */
    for ( r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            scanf("%d", &inputMatrix[r][c]);
            //     ^^ if you are scanning integer numbers... 
        }
    }

    printf("\nrows: %d cols: %d elements:\n",rows,cols);  
    for( r = 0; r < rows; r++) {  
        for( c = 0; c < cols; c++) {  
            printf("%d ", inputMatrix[r][c]);
            // ...  ^^ you should print integer numbers
        }  
        printf("\n");  
    }  

    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)  {  
        for (c = 1; c < cols; c++) {
        //      ^^^ I don't know why you skip this here
            a = inputMatrix[r][c];
            //^ You have to assign, not to compare!
            square[r] += a * a;
            //           ^^^^^ no need to call pow()
        }  
        printf("Sum of squares of row %d: %lld\n",r,square[r]);
        //             square contains int ^^
        // It would be nice and safer if you check here if square == 0 to avoid a
        // division by zero and probably detect bad input data
    }  

    for ( r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) {
        // It's far more efficient to precalculate this term, even if compilers
        // could be smart enough to do it for you. You may want to store those
        // values in an array of doubles instead of the (sum of) squares
        k = 1.0 / sqrt(square[r]);
        for( c = 0; c < cols; c++ ) {  
            norm[r][c] = k * inputMatrix[r][c] ;
            // again,  ^ assign not compare
        }  
    }

    // you can add the printf to the previous loop...
    printf("\nNormalized Matrix:\n");  
    for( r = 0; r < rows; r++) {  
        for( c = 0; c < cols; c++) {  
            printf("%.3lf ", norm[r][c]);
            //      ^^^^^ norm contains double 
        }  
        printf("\n");  
    }  

    return 0;  
}
```

I keep the input matrix of integer type, but it would be better to use double for that too. As i added a print loop for the original matrix, the final output is:

```
rows: 2 cols: 3 elements:
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
Sum of squares of row 0: 13
Sum of squares of row 1: 61

Normalized Matrix:
0.277 0.555 0.832 
0.512 0.640 0.768
```

Comment: Unclear why continuing with `float` in `float a;  a = inputMatrix[r][c];`.  Perhaps `long long` for `a` and `square[]`?

Comment: @chux ops, you are right I've missed that. I edited the answer and used int as the OP initialize its matrix so, but, as said, I think it would be better using double from the biginning.

Comment: @chux I wanted to keep it simple, but on second thought, I agree with you that it's better address that possible issue

Comment: I looked into how to define a integer that was twice as wide with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25982992/2410359) .  But I agree with you, this is more like a FP problem fro `double`, etc.

Comment: @Bob chux Thank you so much. I did not include the first row for it is my constant in the matrix. but it's ok.. thank you for the big help.

Comment: @GenevieveBaguhinEngalan you're welkome and thanks for comment, I'll correct my answer accordingly. Can you please elaborate a little on the constness of the first element? It's where you store the known vector of a linear system of equations?

Comment: @Bob__ this is a linear programming problem where my constraints are Ax_i<=b. for example I have a set of constraints, 

2x_1 + x_2 <=1500
x_1 + x_2 <= 1200

then I will write this in matrix as:
1500 2 1
1200 1 1

That's why I did not include the first element.

Comment: @Bob__ this is a linear programming problem where my constraints are Ax_i<=b. for example I have a set of constraints,   

2x_1 + x_2 <=1500  
x_1 + x_2 <= 1200  
  
then I will write this in matrix as:  
1500 2 1  
1200 1 1  
  
That's why I did not include the first element.