# Math operations with long long in c

Tags: c, algorithm, math

Given `long long x`, `long long y`, and `int z`, how can trunc((`x`+`y`+`z`)/3) be calculated using fully defined operations in C but excluding `unsigned long long` and wider arithmetic?

(trunc(*x*) is “rounding toward zero”: It is *x* if *x* is an integer and otherwise is the next integer toward zero.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Unfortunately i cannot use it

Comment: @deniskalistrat: You need to specify the entire problem in the problem statement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Imagine that i need to find the avg of three numbers (two of them will be long long and one will be just normal int), how can I calculate it properly in c, assuming that i cannot use anything bigger than long long type?

Comment: @deniskalistrat: Is the updated problem statement I wrote correct and complete? It says fractions are rounded toward zero. Does it matter in which directions fractions are rounded? Could they be to-nearest or always down (toward −∞, same as floor(x)), or does it matter?

Comment: duplicate: [Average of 3 long integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23949785/995714)

Comment: For 2 `long long`, perhaps [Take the average of two signed numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29834136/2410359)

Comment: Vote to reopen is premature until OP confirms the edit is correct and complete.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the average of two integers `x` and `y` without the risk of overflow as follows (pseudocode):

```
int average = (x and y have the same sign)
    ? x + (y - x) / 2
    : (x + y) / 2;
```

This is not symmetric due to integer truncation. If you want to always round towards 0, you need to do something slightly more complicated:

```
int average = (x and y have the same sign)
    ? (x and y are both even or both odd)
          ? x + (y - x) / 2
          : x + (y - x - sgn(x)) / 2
    : (x + y) / 2;
```

where `sgn` is the signum function (-1, 0, or +1 depending on whether the argument is negative, zero, or positive). There are lots of implementations of `sgn(x)`, but one nice one is: `(x > 0) - (x < 0)`.

If you want to always round down...that's left as an exercise. :)

Comment: Hmmm, consider (6,3) and (3,6) give different answers, so not commutative.

Comment: For me, `printf("%d\n", 6 + (3 - 6) / 2);` --> 4 and `printf("%d\n", 3 + (6 - 3) / 2);` --> 5.  Are you using C99 or later?  Early C is looser defined

Comment: `6+(3-6)/2` → `6+(-3)/2` → `6+-1` → `5`. `3+(6-3)/2` → `3+3/2` → `3+1` → `4`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - I stand corrected (and so does my answer) .Thanks for pointing out this issue. :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Right you are. I updated my answer to deal with that.

Comment: For me with new update, `printf("%d\n", average(1,3));` --> 1. Expect 2.  Overflows with `average(INT_MIN, -1)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - *sigh*. Thanks again. As delusional programmers often say, "There! I've fixed the last bug!"

Answer (score 0):

To average two unsigned numbers in C, you can use the fact that (L + R)/2 = L + (R-L)/2. Using the form on the right hand side guarantees the arithmetic will not overflow.

Comment: *"Using the form on the right hand side guarantees the arithmetic will not overflow"* - not really, it can overflow if R is positive and L negative.

Comment: The question is for signed numbers, not unsigned.