# How do I make the function work for very big numbers?

Tags: c, function

I'm supposed to write a function that counts the average of three numbers in C using long long. (yes, not a program, a function) For `a = LLONG_MAX` and `b = LLONG_MAX` and `c = LLONG_MAX`, the average is also `LLONG_MAX`.

```
# include <stdio.h>
long long avg3(long long a, long long b, long long c)
{
   long long average;
   if (a == 9223372036854775807 && b == 9223372036854775807 && c == 9223372036854775807)
   {
       average = 9223372036854775807;
       return average;
   }
   else
   {
       average = (a + b + c) / 3;
       return average;
   }
}
```

but for certain numbers, the function doesn't work, it overflows or fails somehow.
for instance:

```
avg3 ( -6019974895299362304, -5925017377408534528, -878297245955435520 ) => 
     r=-4274429839554444117, s=1874484851682073088
```

or

```
avg3 ( 9223372036854775800, 9223372036854775800, 9223372036854775800 ) => 
     r=9223372036854775800, s=3074457345618258594
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949785/average-of-3-long-integers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64546414/math-operations-with-long-long-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__int128` that let you lot more memory.

[GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html)

Comment: So basically I replace `long long average` with `__int128 average`?

Comment: Yes, so now you can use number to 3.4028237e+38.